Alternative to $this->requestAction in CakePHP 4
In CakePHP 4, I've facing issue on  $this->requestAction
I get an error which is error: [Error] Call to undefined method App\View\AppView::requestAction()
My Code:
<?php
if(empty($newsfeed) || count($newsfeed) < 4){
echo $html_data = $this->requestAction('/members/adminnewsfeed');
echo '<li id="no_record" class="media media1" style="text-align: center;">  Challenge Launched. </li>';
}?>

However, since it's deprecated in CakePHP 4.x, I'm seeking recommendations for alternative approaches to achieve similar functionality.
I am expecting an alternative of $this->requestAction so I can easily manage same code in upgrading cake php 4.

requestAction was always a bit of an abomination. :-) The "right" way to code this is generally to move the code that does that processing and returns that data into a service class, which anything that needs to use it can reference without needing to set up a whole request object.
From your provided code, it also seems that perhaps a view cell would be a way to go. Do you actually need a user-facing controller action for /members/adminnewsfeed, or is it only used in scenarios like this?

I aim to transmit data from the view page to the controller without requiring submission, and after processing in the controller, I intend to return the output here.
Consider this example:
$count_highhug = $this->requestAction('/members/highhug', array('pass' => array($val['cat']['id'])));
In this instance, I seek to pass the data $val['cat']['id'] to the highhug function within the memberscontroller.

There's no need to have a controller involved in any of that. Create a service class like \App\Service\MembersService, have a function in it called highhug or whatever, then in your view (this is arguably the wrong place to do make these calls, but one thing at a time...) you do $service = new \App\Service\MembersService(); $count = $service->highhug($val['cat']['id']);

The critical point here is that controllers are not the only classes that can do processing, and in fact should generally do very little of it.
